# Fixed div on scroll... need to push body down to compensate for div height?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, fixed

I'm able to set a nav div to be fixed when scrolled past it, however I need to extend the jQuery code to add a CSS element to the body to push it down by the height of the div to compensate for the jump that happens when the div is made to be fixed.

The jQuery code I'm using is

```
var $window = $(window),
   $stickyEl = $('nav#main'),
   elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

$window.scroll(function() {
    $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
});
```

I need to add a margin-top of 40px to the body tag when the .sticky class is applied.

Is there a CSS rule I can make that sets margin-top:40px to body, but when .sticky is shown? Something like the opposite of child css elements (>) ?

Comment: Why don't you set a padding to the sticky element?

Comment: A padding will affect the sticky div, and increase it's size. I want to push the overal page content down to compensate for the jump the page will make to go back up to the top (when the sticky div is fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specificity relationships only work one way, so there aren't selectors to target parents of elements, and although there are a few ways to do so, I don't think they fully apply to your situation.

I think what you might want to do here is not use toggleClass and just do the check manually, this way you can expand your "callback".

```
$window.scroll(function() {
  if($window.scrollTop() > elTop) {
    $stickyEl.addClass('sticky');
    $(body).css("marginTop", "40px");
  } else {
    $stickyEl.removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

Or you could just have a hidden div to be the spacer and just use a class to show/hide it, then do something like:

```
$window.scroll(function() {
    $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    $myHiddenDiv.toggleClass('show', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
});
```

The other option you could try to do is mess around with the :before selector and create a div that would act as a spacer.

Comment: I used your idea but only the last part. Simply replaced $myHiddenDiv with body and toggled a class of 'nav-spacer' to add a margin-top or 40px. Thanks!

Comment: Nice idea, thanks for: $(body).css("marginTop", "40px");

Answer (score 2):

just add your sticky class to your body than you cant simply use

```
body.sticky {margin-top: 40px;}
body.sticky nav#main {poistion: fixed;}
```

when you remove the class sticky both are reset to normal.

Comment: Actually using a parent element is probably your best bet, seeing as your doing fixed positioning you shouldn't see any issues w/ the parent not having position:relative, but if you end up having the need to do that you're going to have to deal with it since the rest of your document is contained in the body/parent container. Other than little bit, this is way more elegant than what i had :P

Comment: Because the class applies when the window is scrolled to whatever element is set. So if I set it to body, as soon as the window is scrolled, it'll make my div jump up to the top of the window. Thanks for the idea though!